# Вкладка MySQL в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Появился очередной вопрос "как сделать так, чтоб в delphi появилась вкладка MySQL". Большое спасибо, жду ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Установить пакет компонентов MyDAC

Comment: МайДак платная

Comment: Не такая и дорогая для профессионального разработчика.